# When boss jdata/content folder is emptied?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

When I deploy my jars and wars, I can see in the logs file that they are placed in data/content folder. Also an entry in the standalone.xml is added for each deployment.
The problem is that somehow that folder gets empty and the next time I start the server it throws an error because it can't find the files.
I have to manually edit the standalone.xml to remove the deployments but why in the first place the files are removed? How can I avoid this problem?

I am using ubuntu and jboss eap 6.4

Thanks for your help

Comment: EAP 6.4, are you sure? That version has not been released yet. That said it sounds like a bug and you should probably file an issue.

Comment: it's the beta version. I can see in the logs: Content /opt/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/data/content/3a/e0cff91d7f40d5b4c7cefbbd1eab34025bdc15 is obsolete and will be removed

Comment: I'd suggest you call support if you're using the beta.